# Get featured image with custom size outside WordPress

Tags: php, uploads, post-thumbnails, media, images

I have a WordPress blog which is hosted as a sub directory of a web application. The WordPress installation is untouched and modifications are done at the theme level. The web application home page needs to display the recent blog posts. So I have the following code for displaying the recent posts:

```
    $array = array();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status=:publish AND post_type=:post_type";
    $stmt = $this->dbj->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':publish' => 'publish',
        ':post_type' => 'post'
    ));

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $id = $row["ID"];
            if ($row["post_name"] == '') {
                $slug = $row["ID"];
            } else {
                $slug = $row["post_name"];
            }
            $content1 = strip_tags($row["post_content"]);

            $image_prepare = $this->dbj->prepare('SELECT
    wp_postmeta.meta_id,
    wp_postmeta.post_id,
    wp_postmeta.meta_key,
    wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM
    wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = :meta_key
AND wp_posts.post_parent = :pid');

            $image_prepare->execute(
                array(
                    ':pid' => $id,
                    ':meta_key' => '_wp_attached_file'
                )
            );

            $image_fetch = $image_prepare->fetchAll();

            foreach ($image_fetch as $image_row) {
                $image_name = $row['post_title'];
                $image_path = $image_row['meta_value'];
            }

            if (strlen($content1) > 200) {
                $content = substr($content1, 0, 200) . '...';
            } else {
                $content = nl2br($content1);
            }

            $array[] = array(
                'image_path' => $image_path,
                'image_name' => $image_name,
                'slug' => $row["post_name"],
                'content' => $content,
                'title' => $row['post_title']
            );
        }
    return $array;
    }
```

I am getting the full size image url. I have done resizing in my `functions.php` file in theme:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

add_image_size('home-size', 214, 300);
add_image_size('home-featured', 300, 300);
add_image_size('jobs-thumb', 50, 75);
```

The problem is that resized images in uploads directory do not always have `image-name-300x300.jpg` for `home-featured`. Instead they have random values for height depending on the image's ratio in file name (Ex: `image-name-300x220.jpg`). And I have regenerated the thumbnails again but still same file name. How do I get `'home-featured'` for above solution?

Answer (score 1):

This question is not about WordPress, but about PHP. Anyway, if you know the full image name, you know the desired filename has the following structure: `imagename-300x*`. This you can feed to the [PHP function glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), which will return an array of all files matching the given pattern. So, supposing `$image` contains the path to the full image you would do:

```
$matches = glob ($image . '-300x');
$homef-image = $matches[0];
```